# Use Public Property in connectedCallback()

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm looking to use the value of a public property set within Lightning App Builder in the connectedCallback() function. How do go about getting the property (objectName in the snippet below) into this function?

.js

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class redirect extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

@api objectName = '';

connectedCallback() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: objectName,
            actionName: 'home'
        }
    });
}
}
```

js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
</targets>
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage">
        <property name="objectName" type="String"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `objectName` is a class property of `redirect` use `this.objectName` inside `connectedCallback` methos to refer to it

```
connectedCallback() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: this.objectName,
            actionName: 'home'
        }
    });
}
```